# Supress startup messages on stdout?

Tags: tcsh, suse, stdout, interactive

I'm using `tcsh`, and have to source a group `.cshrc` file. This file echoes some messages, which is fine for normal shells, but causes problems with programs like `scp` and `rsync`. I can see the solution taking one of a few forms, but am unable to implement any of them.

#### Only execute echos when appropriate

I've scoured the `rsync` and `tcsh` man pages, but I can't find any variables that are guaranteed to be set or unset when it is called from ssh/rsync/whatever. `$PROMPT` is the same as normal, `$shlvl` is 1, and nothing else looks promising.

#### Redirect to stderr

rsync/scp/etc don't seem to care about what comes over stderr, so if I could, I would

```
echo $MSG >&2
```

But this doesn't even work from the shell. Instead, it writes `$MSG` to a file named `2`. When I look through the history, it seems that something (xterm? readline? tcsh?) is inserting spaces, so what was actually run was

```
echo $MSG > & 2
```

So the observed behavior makes sense given the actual input to tcsh.

#### Redirect to /dev/stderr

I've also tried

```
echo $MSG > /dev/stderr
```

Which works for `ssh`, but for `scp` and `rsync`, I get the message '`/dev/stderr: Permission denied.`' and the key difference seems to be where the file is symlinked. Adding `ls -l /dev/stderr /proc/self/fd/2` to the cshrc file shows

```
# For ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 Apr 11 09:58 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwx------ 1 <me> <mygrp> 64 May 24 14:34 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/6

# For scp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 Apr 11 09:58 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
l-wx------ 1 <me> <mygrp> 64 May 24 15:07 /proc/self/fd/2 -> pipe:[378204842]
```

However, since the permission denied message comes across on stderr, the scp/rsync process is able to do its thing, so I can live with this solution, but would rather not get this spurious error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom I use is

```
if ( $?prompt ) then
    # interactive commands here
endif
```

note that it's spelled `$prompt` (lowercase), not `$PROMPT`.

```
% echo $prompt
%U%m%u:%B%~%b%#

% ssh localhost 'echo $prompt'
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password: 
prompt: Undefined variable.
```

If `$prompt` is always set, then one of your startup files might be setting it unconditionally.

It should go inside the `if ( $?prompt )` test too, e.g.

```
if ( $?prompt ) then
    set prompt='%B%m%b %C3>'

    # interactive commands here
endif
```

Testing if the output is a terminal might work too.

```
if ({ test -t 0 }) then
    # interactive commands here
endif
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason, my `$prompt` is always `%B%m%b %C3>`

Comment: Is it being set in your group `.cshrc`?  Move the `set prompt...` inside the `if ( $?prompt )` test as well.

Comment: You're right. Shortly after I posted my comment, I found where $prompt was being set, and fixed things as you suggested. `test -t 0` works for me also.