# Welcome banner stopping scp

Tags: ssh, login, scp, profile

Our team decided to add a welcome banner to all our hosts. A team member, instead of adding the message in `/etc/motd` added the message with `echo` in `~/.cshrc`.

This is breaking `scp` between the hosts. Can someone explain how this is breaking `scp`? Is `cshrc` loaded even when you do `scp` ? And how will some echo messages in it break it?

I am not aware of the internal workings of `scp`.

The message we added in `~/.cshrc` :

```
echo "##############################################################################"
echo "                              Alert! Aler! Alert! Alert! Alert! Alert!"
echo "This is a restricted box, any actions performed here will be reported to xxx@yyy.com"
echo "##############################################################################"
```

Comment: Related: [suppress startup messages on stdout](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39271/supress-startup-messages-on-stdout) . The `.cshrc` file is always read, even in non-interactive shells like the ones started by scp. Anything that may produce output, such as `echo` or `stty`, needs be be inside an `if ($?prompt )` statement. There are other, safer ways to display banner messages (such as the `Banner` directive in the ssh server config), but an admin needs to set this up.

Comment: Which machine(s) have the `echo` commands in their `.cshrc`: the local machine running `scp` , and/or the remote server?  Please describe "breaking": what exact `scp` command is run, and what output/error message is produced?

Comment: @JigglyNaga here is the output 

`[aime@abc ~]$ scp 20160830210005defaults.conf aime@xyz:/scratch/aime
aime@xyz's password:
########################################################################################################`

Comment: Your colleague made a typo in the banner, too. Might I suggest greater attention to detail in your organisation? And some peer review?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Commands running on top of the `ssh` transport do not expect large amounts of output before they can start their server. This will affect a number of utilities.

The solution is to have your administration team print the message only if *stdout* is connected to a terminal.

```
if ( $?prompt ) then
    echo "Secure machine message..."
    echo "More warnings"
    echo "Etc."
endif
```

Better still, you wouldn't put this in `.cshrc` at all, but instead the message content itself would go in `/etc/issue.net`, which is displayed *before* login. This may need enabling in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` though, with a line like this:

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

Comment: What are "large amounts of data"?

Comment: @MaxRied I'd suggest that at best it's anything much larger than a prompt. For some commands it may be anything at all. I don't know exactly - I've never measured it.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot print anything in non-interactive session. That breaks any clients that use a strict protocol, such as SFTP or SCP.

---

Use `/etc/motd` (which is used for interactive sessions only).

Or use `sshd_config` directive `Banner`.

Or test for interactive session before printing anything (e.g. by testing an existence of `TERM` or `prompt` variables).

---

For background, see my answer to Server Fault question [SSH MOTD per user](https://serverfault.com/q/653399/168875).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to place the lines ABOVE anything in the .cshrc file, because otherwise, it will not allow you to do sftp or ftp or whatever, because it is an interactive shell:

These errors are usually caused by commands in a shell run-control file
(.cshrc, .profile, .bashrc, etc.) that produce output to the
terminal. This output interferes with the communication between the SSH
daemon and the sftp-server subsystem. Examples of such commands
might be date or echo. If you use the mail command to check for mail, it
can cause the error, too.To solve this problem, you should place any commands that will produce
output in a conditional statement that is only executed if the
shell is interactive. (ALL FIXES NEED TO BE at the TOP of the control files for the shell in question.

Brian Baker

Answer (score 0):

It's in `~/.cshrc`. I believe that makes fixing this easy. Change the code in `~/.cshrc` to read

```
echo 1>&2 "##############################################################################"
echo 1>&2  "                              Alert! Aler! Alert! Alert! Alert! Alert!"
echo 1>&2  "This is a restricted box, any actions performed here will be reported to xxx@yyy.com"
echo 1>&2  "##############################################################################"
```